# Gestures to navigate in the viewport

Tags: navigation

Is there a way to turn on gestures to navigate similar to photoshop?
Pinch to zoom, ability to pan/rotate, undo history etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for gestures.

The one thing you can do is go to edit -> preferences -> input and turn on Emulate 3 button mouse to hold alt leftclick instead of mouse3. But still, no gesture support for pinch to zoom etc.

If you have a stylus I'd recommend binding mouse 3 to one of your pen buttons.